# 500 internal server error after terminal commands

Tags: magento2, cache, http-error-500

I have an issue with Magento 2 commands. Every time I do :

`bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`bin/magento cache:flush`

`bin/magento cache:clean`

`rm pub/static, etc...`

...

I get 500 internal server error and I need to refresh 2 to 5 times my browser to see my changes.

Anyone knows what's happening ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working. I still need to do a c:f to see my modified phtml file and then 500 error when I refresh for the first time :(

Comment: c:f is must to see the modification as magento websites run on cache